# Replace underscore with space in image link description

Tags: php

This code loop returns any number of image links.  The variable `$picture->description`returns a string of text with underscores that need to be removed.

```
bluebell_glitter_print_one_piece_with_bubble_skirt_LGG5659WT14_china
```

All coding variations that I have tried either end in a single correct image link or a white screen.

How can I edit this loop so that the `data-caption-desc` has no underscores?

```
if(count($pictures)){               
    foreach($pictures as $picture){
        $output .= '<a href="'.get_option('siteurl').$picture->path.'/'.$picture->filename.'" title="'.$picture->alttext.'" data-caption-title="'.$picture->alttext.'" data-caption-desc="'.$picture->description.'">
                        <img class="wpnggimgcls" src="'.get_option('siteurl').$picture->path.'/thumbs/thumbs_'.$picture->filename.'" style="" />
                    </a>';
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you want in place of the underscore?

Comment: What about str_replace('_', ' ', $picture->deascription)?

Comment: Yup, that what I was thinking @felipsmartins. Here's the doc onerock, http://php.net/str_replace.

Comment: I have tried `data-caption-desc="'str_replace('_', ' ', $picture->description)'"` and it causes white screen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [`str_replace`](http://php.net/str_replace)

```
str_replace('_', ' ', $input_string);
```

`str_replace` will replace a characte with another one.

Full:

```
if(count($pictures)) { 
    foreach($pictures as $picture){
        $output .= '<a 
                      href="'.get_option('siteurl').$picture->path.'/'
                      .$picture->filename.'" title="'.$picture->alttext.
                      '" data-caption-title="'.$picture->alttext.'" 
                        data-caption-desc="'
                        .str_replace('_', ' ',$picture->description).'">
                    <img 
                      class="wpnggimgcls" 
                      src="'.get_option('siteurl').
                        $picture->path.'/thumbs/thumbs_'.
                        $picture >filename.'" style="" />
                    </a>';
    }
}
```

Comment: `.$picture->description.` creates the string `bluebell_glitter_print_one_piece_with_bubble_skirt_LGG5659WT14_china`. How do I store the output of `.$picture->description.` into a veriable?

Comment: This worked perfectly, thanks `data-caption-desc="'
                        .str_replace('_', ' ',$picture->description).'"`

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to replace the "underscore" into whitespace, you then can use `preg_replace()`, as follows:

```
<?php
$strChg='bluebell_glitter_print_one_piece_with_bubble_skirt_LGG5659WT14_china';
echo $strChg;
echo '<br />';
echo '<br />';
$Chg=preg_replace('/_/', ' ', $strChg);
echo $Chg;

?>
```

So, the point is:

```
$Chg=preg_replace('/_/', ' ', $strChg);
```

Comment: Why `preg_replace` if your not using a regex?

Comment: Thanks for the replys.  `.$picture->description.` creates the string `bluebell_glitter_print_one_piece_with_bubble_skirt_LGG5659WT14_china`.  How do I generate the string and insert it into the loop?

Comment: it's okay to use str_replace or preg_replace

Comment: @onerockscott you can use str_replace or preg_replace as I suggested to make sure that the characters supported by it. Here, you can set: preg_replace('/_/',' ',$your-image-path);

Comment: str_replace only support string :p